# Flutter: check internet connection throughout the app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like if I could check if there is internet connection throughout the different pages. I have the following code in my "login" page:

```
 @override
 void initState() {
    subscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      print("Connectivity changed: " + result.toString());
      setState(() {
        _haveInternet = result == ConnectivityResult.mobile || result == ConnectivityResult.wifi;
      });
   });
 }

 @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    subscription.cancel();
  }

  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;
  bool _haveInternet = false;
```

These lines changes the value of `_haveInternet` and show different widgets on the login page based on it (online / offline login).

Now if I am on the login page and turn on and off the wifi / mobile data, the widgets are changing on the login page. If I leave this page, no more it is checking the the internet connection.

I want something similar on all pages of the app. So in case someone logs in offline mode but turns on mobile data later, then the app could realize it and start communicating with a server to send the logged data for example.

I would like to copy-paste the given code to every app page so anywhere the user navigate, it would check always the internet connection but this does not seem like a best practice.

What would be the best way? I would like if it would be easy to add new pages / parts to the app where it is also checking the internet connection.

Comment: You can use `Provider` and `ChangeNotifier`

Comment: If you are free to use third party package, there is nice flutter package available for this. check- https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus. IT is compatible over all platformas.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use provider and check for internet in the root file.

In my opinion, it's better to check for the internet on the home screen or any landing screen because if you check for internet connection in login it will get disposed as you go to the home screen, as a majority of us use pageReplacement.So try by checking to write the internet check function on the home screen.

Save the returned value on the provider, so that you can notify all the listeners to which provider subscribed.

package: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus